# Popping an array from local function in as2

Tags: arrays, function, actionscript, actionscript-2

Why does this pop method returns: `[type Function]`

```
var possibles:Array=new Array(1,2,3,4);
function testpop()
{
  trace( possibles.pop );
}
testpop();
```

This code written in action script 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cause it's a function remember to call it:

```
var possibles:Array=new Array(1,2,3,4);
function testpop()
{
  trace( possibles.pop() );
}
testpop();
```